# WebdriverIO getting all values from a table column

Tags: webdriver-io

As a way of testing myself I am looking at
https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/table-sort-search-demo.html
Now I enter "London" into the search field, and I get 7 rows returned.
I want to try to count the values of the "**salary**" column.

I have found the table has has id of "**example**" and I have managed to get the first row to return a salary using

```
    const locatorString = $(locator);

    console.log(locatorString.$$('td')[5].getText())
```

however, I can't get anything more.
I have tried removing the [5].getText() and I get an object.  Likeise I have managed to get every single item to print (as in every single td) but I can't narrow this down.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From a selector point of view, I think the following would give you an array of all salary column elements
`const salaryArray = $$('#example tr[role="row"] > td:nth-child(6)')`
For example: `salaryArray[0].getText()` would be the first salary

It should just be a matter of looping through those using getText() and parsing to a number format.